# Tensorflow error while training model with RASA NLU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, rasa-nlu

I am using RASA NLU. While training the bot I am getting the following exceptionL

```
a. ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
b. Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

and quite a bit of errors in stack trace as one can see at the end of the post.

Here is snippet of versions I am using for different modules with `python 3.6.8`:

```
tensorboard                        1.8.0
rasa-core                          0.10.1
rasa-nlu                           0.13.0a2
Keras                              2.1.6
```

I ensured the training domain `yaml` is placed in right location and has no errors.

#### Stack Trace:

```
\ML-Python\RASA\Rasa_basic_folder>python ./train_init.py
F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./train_init.py", line 19, in <module>
    agent = Agent('./restaurant_domain.yml', policies = [MemoizationPolicy(max_history = 4), KerasPolicy(featurizer)])
  File "c:\python27\scripts\rasa_core-master\rasa_core\policies\keras_policy.py", line 47, in __init__
    if KerasPolicy.is_using_tensorflow() and not graph:
  File "c:\python27\scripts\rasa_core-master\rasa_core\policies\keras_policy.py", line 64, in is_using_tensorflow
    from keras.backend import _BACKEND
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
  from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "F:\Anaconda-32bit\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
```

Comment: You have tensorflow installed??

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `tensorflow` is not correctly installed. Please try re-installing rasa-core with `pip install -U rasa-core` or even update to the new `rasa` package, which combines rasa-nlu and rasa-core (the old `rasa-core` and `rasa-nlu` are packages are deprecated). You can do so by doing `pip install rasa`.

Answer (score 0):

For you to resolve these tensorflow dependencies - see below.

```
pip install rasa[convert]
```